# How MLO (minimal bootloader) works?

Tags: linux-kernel, embedded-linux, bootloader, texas-instruments, dm814x

I am trying to understand how a MLO is loaded into the on-chip of a SOC and do the minimal configuration. I am using TI DM8168 soc.

I have gone through the following link to understand the MLO or x-loader:

http://omappedia.org/wiki/Bootloader_Project

I got to know that the ROM Code loads the MLO (x-loader) to the on-chip RAM of the SoC which do the minimal configuration and finally loads the uboot (universal bootloader), that finally initiates the linux kernel.

My doubt here is that my on-chip RAM size is 64 KB and the MLO size is 116 KB, then how the ROM code is loading the MLO to the on-chip RAM

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the DM8168 has more than 64KiB internal RAM: as explained in 
the [DM816x AM389x PSP 04.00.01.13 Feature Performance Guide](http://processors.wiki.ti.com/index.php/DM816x_AM389x_PSP_04.00.01.13_Feature_Performance_Guide), it has at least two more blocks of internal RAM, referenced OMC0 and OMC1, both being 256KiB in size.

Those two banks can be used by u-boot according to this document:

*OCMC0 0x40300000 - 0x4033FFFF OCMC 0 will be used by ROM Code and U-boot. Once Linux kernel boots, OCMC0 is free and kernel can use it. If OCMC0 should not be used to load u-boot if loaded using CCS.*

*OCMC1 0x40400000 - 0x4043FFFF OCMC 1 will be used by ROM Code and U-boot. Once Linux kernel boots, OCMC0 is free and kernel can use it.*

From u-boot-omap3/board/ti/ti8168/config.mk, it seems u-boot is using OMC1

TI_LOAD_ADDR = 0x40400000

This would explain why your 116KiB u-boot image can fit in the DM8168 internal RAM.